# Implicit parameter without type in play

Tags: scala, playframework, implicit

Why does the following Play syntax work

```
def handleForm = Action(parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded) { implicit request =>
  val username = request.body.get("username").map(_.head).getOrElse("");
  Ok("Username was " + username)
}
```

Without specifying the type of request, how would the compiler know how to resolve the implicit?

Answer (score 2):

An Action in Play can be seen as a function: `Request[A] => Result`. Internally an Action is defined like `trait Action[A] extends EssentialAction`

The type `A` is actually the one which allows you to put anything in there. As you can see from the code, the Request is defined like this: `trait Request[+A] extends RequestHeader`. Interesting here is also the plus sign (`+`). It is the so-called *covariant annotation*. This covariant type parameter is one which is allowed to vary down as the class is subtyped. It means that if you have something like

`trait List[+A]`

then `List[Int]` is a subtype of `List[AnyVal]` because `Int` is a subtype of `AnyVal`. This means that you may provide an instance of `List[Int]` when a value of type `List[AnyVal]` is expected.

All this allows you to have a super generic request which serves as a base for your action and therefore no compile time troubles should be expected.

---

And something as for why is this all necessary from a more user-related point of view:

From the Play Scala documentation:

> It is often useful to mark the request parameter as implicit so it can
>   be implicitly used by other APIs that need it:
>
> ```
> Action { implicit request =>
>   Ok("Got request [" + request + "]")
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually resolve the implicit, **you** mark the parameter as implicit, for further method calls inside the request handler. Whenever you call a method which accepts an implicit `Request` parameter, the request argument from the request handler will be automatically passed to it. If you wouldn't mark the request argument as implicit, you'd have to explicitly pass the request argument for each method call who needs an implicit request parameter.

**update**: upon your comment I updated your code with type parameters to clarify. So even when you use different `BodyParser`s, your request parameter is still going to be of Request type, so there is no need to convert it, it's just going to be parametrized differently based on your body parser. `request.body` is going to have the same type as the type parameter, `Map[String, Seq[String]]` in this example. If you use a JSON body parser then your `request` parameter would be a `Request[JsValue]`, and the `request.body` is a `JsValue`.

```
def handleForm: Action[Map[String, Seq[String]]] = Action(parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded)({ 
  implicit request: Request[Map[String, Seq[String]]] =>
    val username = request.body.get("username").map(_.head).getOrElse("")
    Ok("Username was " + username)
})
```

**tl;dr** You can just do `Action(...) { request  => ... }` if you don't need an implicit `Request` for further method calls inside the request handler

Comment: How does the compiler know the method accepts an implicit Request parameter? My method `handleForm` simply accepts an implicit parameter called `request` for which the naming is arbitrary?

Comment: your method accepts an explicit Request parameter, which is going to be implicit inside the method's body for the subsequent function calls, like this one: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaForms#Defining-a-form

Comment: oh I see, then there must be a method somewhere that transform `parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded` to `request` type right? Since `parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded.body` returns an error.

Comment: @Kevin I added some explanation, hope that makes clear. It's normal that `parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded.body` returns an error, because `parse.tolerantFormUrlEncoded` is a body parser, not a `Request`. But `request.body` is going to be the right type, corresponding to your type parser